# Simplest way to run a python application the receives data from a web application, processes/manipulates it then pushes it back to the front end

Tags: javascript, python, html, reactjs, web

Goal: A frontend that receives a twitter username that is sent to a python script that then scrapes that users timeline (https://twitter.com/*username*) then simulates text with that user's tweets using Markov Chains. Finally, this output is returned to the front end.

I don't need help with the actual python coding or frontend. I am just lost on how to "actually start working on this", specifically as to what tools to use to execute python scripts and use these in conjunction with a frontend (preferably reactjs).

Thank you so much for your time and advice

Comment: try node-gyp with express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use to approaches:

1. You have to use a python backend web server either Flask or Django (Flask os recommended for this particular purpose). Send the twitter username from the frontend to the python server using `Ajax`, `axios`, or `fetch API`. Do your processing and then send your output to the frontend in the response of that request.
2. Use web Sockets for more dynamic feel